# Cannot insert any entities into a table due to primary key duplication error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class

```
  public partial class Person
  {
      public Person()
      {
          JobNavigation = new HashSet<Job>();
      }
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<Job> JobNavigation { get; set; }
  }
```

I am trying to create two new people and insert them into a database

```
        var newPerson1 = new Person()
        {
            Name = "test"
        };
        var newPerson2 = new Person()
        {
            Name = "test2"
        };

        context.Person.Add(newPerson1);
        context.Person.Add(newPerson2);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

But when I try to save, I get the following error

> The instance of entity type 'Person' cannot be tracked because another
>   instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.
>   When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance
>   with a given key value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.

I checked both people after their creation. Their Id was set to 0 in both cases. So naturally their ids conflict. I want to insert these two people and have their id be automatically generated but I don't see what I am doing wrong here.

This is what my table looks like in SQL server: [image]

Comment: @Noob: EF is well capable of handling more than one item's addition in the same transaction (not being able to do so is a massive gap in transational functionality). Even if that works, the fact that it only works this way would still be indicative of a problem.

Comment: I just tried saving them after adding each new item. But as I expected it didn't make a difference. A new id was not generated and it is still trying to insert a person with id of 0. This time I got the following error: **SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Person'.**

Comment: Your ID column is not an identity column I guess.

Comment: Ok, you were right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` entirely necessary? I think Entity Framework should handle autogenerating the ID if you take that out and just have Id marked with `[Key]`. Otherwise, leaving that annotation in means you'll have to manually set the Primary Key by hand. (Since it's an `int` it'll always default to 0 without intervention.)